# Vertically align elements in different height columns

Tags: css

[I've attached an illustration to help me get my point across!](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LjtKL.jpg)

[image]

So, `DIV 1` and `DIV 2` (children of PARENT DIV) are columns on a page I'm building, and the content within them is not of the same height, so currently their buttons do not line up vertically.

I need to vertically align `BUTTON 1` and `BUTTON 2` (I guess to the bottom of PARENT DIV?);

How do I go about this please?

Thanks!

Comment: Hi SRD, welcome to SO! It sounds like you are going to have to play round with the `position` and `bottom` property. Before you do, I would suggest recreating your question on jsfiddle.net and posting a link here. This will help with the answering process.

Comment: The first thing you obvioulsy have to do is make the colums the same height...and go from there.

Comment: Use CSS flex properties

Answer (score 0):

You can apply position relative and a bottom padding in DIV 1 and DIV 2 to prevent its content to overlap the buttons, whose position should be absolute (maybe bottom: 10px according to your screenshot).

Example: jsfiddle.net/yy87qdmt/1/

Comment: That's great, thank you - but is there a way to do it without fixed heights? The site's responsive so fixed heights are a nuisance...

Comment: Try applying a relative position to the parent div, static to the children divs and split the horizontal positioning of the buttons depending on the children div. As the text in a children div gets bigger, the button will follow the bigger one, as the children div pushes the parent div height

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get away from the position CSS directive, but if you don't want to use bottom, there are numerous jQuery examples that will allow you to logically place your divs.

Alternately (and I know you seem to want to use Divs) but you may be able to use a table easier.

Comment: He tagged only with CSS

Comment: Ahh thanks.   But still may not be a bad idea to offer suggestions he may not of thought of.  But you're right.

Comment: I'm certainly open to other methods, but would need a bit of a pointer! So long as I can keep DIV 1 and DIV 2 as responsive columns, I'm fine with it!

Comment: And you do right! Don't yet forget the vote-up. I need it today

Answer (score 0):

Tested & proofed in firefox-45 and chrome-50

```
<body>
    <main>
        <style scoped>
            main
            {
                flex-direction: row;
                display: flex;
            }
            main > figure
            {
                border: 1px darkgrey solid;
                justify-content: flex-end;
                flex-direction: column;
                box-sizing: border-box;
                display: flex;
            }
            main > figure > :first-child
            {
                background-color: lightgrey;
                flex-grow: 1;
            }
            main > figure > figcaption
            {
                background-color: black;
                color: lightgrey;
                flex-shrink: 1;
            }
        </style>
        <figure>
            <picture>
                <source srcset="mdn-logo-wide.png" media="(min-width: 600px)">
                <img src="mdn-logo-narrow.png" alt="MDN">
            </picture>
            <figcaption>
                Caption 0
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
        <figure>
            <article>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cosectetur...</p>
                <p>...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cosectetur...</p>
                <p>...Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet cosectetur</p>
            </article>
            <figcaption>
                Caption 1
            </figcaption>
        </figure>
    </main>
</body>
```

[image: The screenshot on my firefox 45.0.2]

Answer (score 0):

Flexbox can do that.

```css
.row {
  display: flex;
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
}
.col {
  width: 50%;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 1em;
}
img {
  width: auto;
  max-height: 100%;
}
p {
  text-align: justify;
}
/* the magic */

.col {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
button {
  margin-top: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col">
    <h2>My Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Consequuntur, dignissimos.</p>
    <button>My button</button>
  </div>
  <div class="col">
    <h2>My Heading</h2>
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Molestiae excepturi autem laborum veritatis ipsam odio itaque, dolorem modi ipsum voluptatibus. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Atque assumenda error blanditiis aliquam
      repellendus, necessitatibus doloribus ipsa eveniet natus laborum.</p>
    <button>My button</button>
  </div>
</div>
```